# How is the table of a 3d printer called?

Tags: terminology, 3d-printing

There is this table, flatbed on the 3d printers. I need such a table which can move up and down, and I firmly believe there are such components on the market, but I can't find anything because I am not sure what they are called.

Comment: Just the plate itself, or the whole mechanism to move it up and down also?

Comment: The whole mechanism.

Comment: rakker579 is correct. Google "build plate" comes up with a lot of similar products for 3D printers.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a buildplate :)

Comment: Cool, thank you! How would i define a search for a buildplate with the elevation mechanism?

Comment: CoreXY printers will have moving buildplates, as the kinematics of the nozzle remain fixed in a plane, while the bed will drop as the build progresses. I have an IDEX printer in which the build plate drops but that's not consistent nor exclusive. QIDI Tech printers also have moving build plates. A general search doesn't provide usefully narrowed results.

Comment: I used to see those in stratasys machines, but they are custom built.

Answer (score 1):

Although technically not the buildplate itself, for the mechanism that drives the plate you can also try **linear stage** or **translation stage** or **precision stage**.